# What does "attempted solutions" mean?

Tags: meaning

> An all-knowing God would know that evil exists; an all-powerful God
> would be able to prevent it occurring; and an all-good God would not
> want it to exist. But evil continues to occur. This serious challenge
> to belief in the Theists’ God has been much discussed by philosophers.
> It is known as the Problem of Evil. In a later section we will examine
> it in some detail, together with several **attempted solutions** to it.
> Here it should at least make us wary about claims that the Design
> Argument provides conclusive evidence for the existence of a supremely
> good God.

How should I understand "attempted solutions"?
Is it "attempts to solve" or "failed solutions"?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It does mean "attempted solutions" as others have pointed out -- however, specifically it means that *philosophers* have failed to solve the problem of evil; that means that they have failed to solve it in a way that leaves no room for argument by anyone.

The subtext here is that the author believes that a failure to solve the problem this way means that there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

It means "attempts to solve", but has the subtext of "but we cannot be sure that we *have* solved it."

Fair enough, I suppose. Philosophical discussions rarely ever do succeed in reaching a conclusion, and when you're arguing over entities which don't exist, then there are obviously no successful conclusions to be reached.

Bottom line: all anyone can do in such discussions is guess.